# Internet connection name increments and won't reset

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I'm having a problem with my internet connection name:

[image: numbered connection]

I created a connection named 'RDS', deleted it and then re-created it. It displays as above 'RDS 2'. Everytime I delete it the connection number increments by 1.
How can I reset it to none?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but `devmgmt.msc` might show the extra network interfaces.

Comment: @grawity Sadly it doesn't display anything about ghost interfaces. Maybe uninstalling the network card's driver completely will also remove these. I'll post back here if it does anything.

Comment: Ah, hmm, how about *Command Prompt* (elevated) → `set DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1` → `devmgmt.msc` → enable the "Show hidden devices" option?

Comment: @grawity Forgot to mention that I have this option already set. It doesn't display any ghost interfaces. And uninstalling the driver won't reset it either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Regedit
2. Go to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\
3. Back up the "Network" tree so that if Windows freaks out, you can go into safe mode and reimport it
4. Search for RDS under the Network tree
5. For each version of RDS, you will have a GUID with sub-Key of Connection. Delete the GUID that is the parent of the Connection key (but not the GUID above it, which is a child of the "Network" key)
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each item under the network tree
7. Reboot